# Javascript: Using variables to find an average

Tags: javascript, variables, average

I am in a tech class as a library science student and the following instruction on some homework is confusing me. I've been on it for... longer than I want to admit.

"Create a variable that stores a student's test average.
The student's test scores are: 90, 82, 85, 100.
Don't forget to take into account how math works!
Use document.write to output "The average is : " followed by the average"

I am not entirely sure what this is asking me and everything I have tried has failed so this is my last hope as Google, the PowerPoint, and the book are not helping me. I'd really like to get this done so any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried to ask verification from the Professor?

Comment: You need to add everything you've tried to your question. There may be a simple bug that you've missed.

Comment: OP, it's also difficult to work out what part of the question is causing you problems. If it's "What is a variable?" then you really need to go back to your tutor and ask for help because if you can't answer that basic and fundamental question then you are going to really struggle in later classes. I say this not to be condescending but urge you to get the help you need. Sadly SO isn't here to guide people through the early stages of coding, but to offer assistance with issues people have with code they've already written. Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

> Create a variable that stores a student's test average.

Using "var" keyword you can define variables in JS. In JS, variables are loosely typed, understand it this way - you can define a string and number variable using "var" keyword.

```
var studentAverage = 0;
```

> The student's test scores are: 90, 82, 85, 100.

This is a JS array. This is an array of numbers, you could have defined array of string in similar fashion - ["maths", "science", "social"]. Also read about JS object.

```
var studentScore = [90, 82, 85, 100];
```

> Don't forget to take into account how math works!

This is like a FOR loop in any other language. `var i=0;` will be executed only once and `i<studentScore.length;i++` will be executed for each iteration until `i<studentScore.length`.

```
var studentScoreTotal = 0; 
for(var i=0;i<studentScore.length;i++){ 
    studentScoreTotal = studentScoreTotal + studentScore[i];
    studentAverage = studentScoreTotal/(i+1);
}
```

> Use document.write to output "The average is : " followed by the
>   average

`document` represents you HTML document and `document.write` will do a write on the HTML document.

```
document.write("The average is : " + studentAverage);
```

---

Complete code snippet:

```
var studentAverage = 0;
var studentScore = [90, 82, 85, 100];
var studentScoreTotal = 0; 
for(var i=0;i<studentScore.length;i++){
    studentScoreTotal = studentScoreTotal + studentScore[i];
    studentAverage = studentScoreTotal/(i+1);
}
document.write("The average is : " + studentAverage);
```

---

You have mentioned you have tried all means but coming to SO as last resort, but you really need to learn the [Javascript step by step](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=learn%20javascript&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=8L5sVpKYNsG9ugT0n5qgBA#q=learn%20javascript%20step%20by%20step). You should have been explained before giving the assignment, nevertheless please start learning JS step-by-step, and in future these kind of extremely basic things should not confuse you.

Comment: Given the level of the OP's understand it might be useful to expand on some of the areas. e.g.: `[90, 82, 85, 100]` is an array, basically a list of things; perhaps explain how the loop works.

Comment: @Andy Added some stuff.

Comment: @MrDownVoter: Please explain down vote. Don't just down vote and run away.

Answer (score 0):

For a variable in javascript u use this simple syntax

```
var name = something;
```

In this case

```
var average = (90 + 82 + 85 + 100)/4;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I think I had added an extra character somewhere by mistake so it wasn't working. I've looked at everything in this post, started from scratch, and now it works. I really appreciate it, everyone. Now I can stop crying. :)